# Powershell function not working on first call

Tags: powershell

I'm using a fairly simple powershell script to include a set of supporting scripts into my main one.

Whenever a file isn't present, I display a notice in the terminal, works fine. I also want to write the notice to my logfile.

So I wrote a simple function to create a timestamp:

```
function psa_get_timestamp {
    return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date);
}
```

That function works fine, **but not the first time when I call it.**

```
# Set logfile
$logfile = join-path -path $PSScriptRoot -childpath "ps-admin_log.txt";

# Create array of needed files
$supporting_files = @(
    '/resources/requirements/environment.ps1',
    '/resources/loggers/logger.ps1',
    '/resources/menus/menus.ps1',
    '/resources/views/headers.ps1'
    );

# Include supporting files, throw non-fatal error if fails
foreach($support_file in $supporting_files) {

  $file = join-path -path $PSScriptRoot -childpath $support_file;

    if(Test-Path $file) {
    . $file;
    Write-Output "$(psa_get_timestamp) Successfully included file: $file" | Out-file $logfile -append
    } else {
    # Throw non-fatal error in terminal and write it to logfile
    Write-Host "! Notice: Could not include supporting file: $file" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
    Write-Output "$(psa_get_timestamp) ! Notice: Could not include supporting file: $file" | Out-file $logfile -append
    }
}
```

My logfile looks like this (notice the missing timestamp on the first line):

```
��  S u c c e s s f u l l y   i n c l u d e d   f i l e :   <file_name>
 [ 0 1 / 2 5 / 1 9   1 9 : 2 1 : 3 1 ]   S u c c e s s f u l l y   i n c l u d e d   f i l e :    <file_name>
 [ 0 1 / 2 5 / 1 9   1 9 : 2 1 : 3 1 ]   S u c c e s s f u l l y   i n c l u d e d   f i l e :    <file_name>
 [ 0 1 / 2 5 / 1 9   1 9 : 2 1 : 3 1 ]   S u c c e s s f u l l y   i n c l u d e d   f i l e :    <file_name>
```

**Why does my function not work on the first call?**

This is the error on the first call:

```
psa_get_timestamp : The term 'psa_get_timestamp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At <scriptlocation>:19 char:21
+     Write-Output "$(psa_get_timestamp) Successfully included file: $f ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (psa_get_timestamp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When using `-Verbose`:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target
"<logfile_location>".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target
"<logfile_location>".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target
"<logfile_location>".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target
"<logfile_location>".
```

Comment: I might try using `-Verbose` on your first `Write-Output` and see if it throws any more information at you. Otherwise though, and this doesn't really explain your problem, would you try using something like `Get-Date -Format O` in your function instead? It gives just as much information as your custom `Get-Date` setup and might work better out of the box.

Comment: In fact, that's exactly what I use for this kind of logging in my scripts. With something more like `Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$(Get-DateTimeString) : logging information"`

Comment: where in your script is the function _defined_? if it is defined AFTER the reference to it ... you may not get anything because it doesn't yet exist. ///// PoSh works from the start to the end of a script ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey THIS! The function is in the supporting `logger.ps1` file, which is included in the second iteration of the loop. Thus the function isn't defined in the first iteration. Switching `logger.ps1` to the first place in the array solved it. You can add it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: @rpm192 - kool! glad to have helped & i will add it as an answer ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way that "only works *after* 1st run" happens is when the item in question is NOT defined before the 1st call. such as when you have a call to a function on line 3 but don't define it until line 33 ... [*grin*]

PoSh runs from start-of-script to end-of-script and won't know that the function being referred to *exists at all*, much less being able to run  he code.

the usual fix is to ensure that the definition is before the 1st use. that is why scripting/coding guides tend to recommend putting all your initialization items - including function definitions - at the top of your script.